# Why is my redirect to my frontend not working (Express and React)

Tags: reactjs, express

I have a react frontend that sends data to backend and then in the backend I save the data, however when i redirect to another page after saving to database it does not go, however , the data is actually saved in the database. Below is the code

index.js (Backend)

```
app.post('/saveImg' , async (req , res) => {
  const {image} = req.body

  const cropData = new CropInfo({
    image: image
  })

  //Save the entry
  await cropData.save()

  res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/login')
})
```

This is how the frontend is sending the data

```
const confirmPicture =   () => {
    //THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO INSERT THE CODE TO SEND Image TO BACKEND
     axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:4000/saveImg",
      data: {
        image: imgSrc
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log("res", res.data.message);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("error in request", err);
    })

    
  }
```

I have a react route http://localhost:3000/login which loads a login page however for some reason the redirect in the backend is not working. Any advice on how to make it work? Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: How is the front-end sending the request?  If it's an AJAX request then the browser wouldn't redirect the user by default.

Comment: @David It is an axios request

Comment: In that case you'd have to perform the redirect client-side, or just make it a normal form post.  AJAX requests don't redirect the user, because that's kind of the point of AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the response back to frontend like `res.json({message: "ok"})` and in react do programatically redirect based on the response back.

```
  import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
  
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  fetch(URL,{OPTIONS})
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(
    (result) => {
      if(result.message === "ok") {
      navigate("/login"); 
      }
    })
```

If you are using axios:

```
 axios.post(URL, {...})
  .then(function (response) {
    if(response.message === "ok") {
     navigate("/login")
    }
  })
```

Comment: I have added the axios call in the question, can you kindly tell me what to change? I am a beginner at this react stuff

Comment: First send response from the express as something like res.json({message: "ok"})

Comment: Then, on front end inside axios while getting response use navigate("/path")

Comment: I am getting this error "useNavigate" cannot be called inside a callback

Comment: Check I have improve the code. First you need to import the library at the top. And inside component at the top write `const navigate = useNavigate()`. Then, inside the axios response function write `navigate("/login")`

Comment: It did not redirect , when i click the button nothing happens apart from the data being saved to database

Comment: Have you passed response from express to the frontend. Use console to check.

Comment: The console.log returned a super long object. I did const response = res.json({message: "ok"}) console.log(response)})

Comment: In frontend inside the callback put console.log(response.data). In axios you don't have to convert response to json.

Comment: It worked. Basically the message "ok" was returned in an object of data so i just grabbed that message from the object